# не работают стили в админ панели Joomla 3.9.18

Tags: css, joomla, joomla3, админка

помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему. Почему то не работают стили в админ панели Joomla. версия 3.9.18. До появления этой ошибки, была проблема на хостинге с версией php. страницы вообще не открывались, теперь они открываются но уже без стилей. Джумлу обновили, заново залили папку templates, но никак. В чем может быть проблема?